# Printing size of data on stack in bytes

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, byte, sizeof

I am attempting to mimic the behavior of `sizeof` in `C` within `x86-assembly` i.e to print the size of data pushed onto the stack in bytes starting from before `push` operations to the current stack pointer (after `push` operations) using the `write` syscall.

I am attempting to achieve this by storing the memory address of the stack pointer into the `edp` register/base pointer before `push` operations. And subtracting the value of `ebp - esp` and storing within `eax` after `push` operations. Finally I print the `eax` integer value to `stdout`

For example:

```
section .text
global  _start

_start:
    ; set the frame pointer to the beginning of the stack before-
    ; data is pushed.
    mov   ebp, esp

    push  byte 0x00       ; <- null terminating byte/string truncation
    push  0x64636261 ; <- data

    mov   eax, ebp
    sub   eax, esp   ; start of stack - end of stack  = sizeof(data) stored in eax

    mov   edx, 4
    mov   ecx, eax
    mov   ebx, 1
    mov   eax, 4
    int   0x80

    mov  eax, 1
    int  0x80
```

compile with:

```
nasm -f elf32 -g test.asm && ld -melf_i386 test.o -o test
```

When compiling this code I receive no stdout.

The expected stdout is:

```
5
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? How do I correctly store the size of the string on the stack (in bytes) in `eax` and print the integer/size to `stdout`.

Comment: There's no system call for printing integers. You'll have to convert the value 5 to a string, and then print that.

Comment: Or Perhaps I could use printf?

Comment: Moreover, the `write` system call expects a *pointer* to the data in the `ecx` register, not the data itself.  So you have to put it somewhere in memory.

Comment: You're passing 2 separate lengths, instead of a pointer.  Just `mov ecx, esp` if you want to write 4 bytes of binary data.